# Python - Deleting multi files

Tags: python, python-2.7, delete-file

I'm trying to deleting multi files.
I'm using this script, but for some reason it deletes only the first 4 and not the rest. if i'm splitting it to 2 scripts it works...what's my problem?

```
def fileDeleter():
    try:
        os.remove('apps.csv')
        os.remove('columns.txt')
        os.remove('columns_boot.txt')
        os.remove('output.txt')
        os.remove('routes.csv')
        os.remove('route_apps.txt')
        os.remove('route_domain.txt')
        os.remove('route_hosts.txt')
        os.remove('start.txt')
        os.remove('space.txt')
    except OSError:
        pass
```

My point is to handle them silently, if the file excites then delete - if not pass. the user does not need to see error that the file is not there. When I added errors, the only one that i got is

`WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified: *filename*`

whice is fine, becuse I don't have all the files all the time. but when I do, the script does not delete all of them.

Comment: What is the error? I think it will be helpful if the `except:` isn't just `pass`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once an error is caught, the program continues. What you need to do is attempt to remove each file at a time and check to see if there is an error.

```
fileList = ['apps.csv', 'columns.txt', 'columns_boot.txt', 'output.txt', 'routes.csv', 'route_apps.txt', 'route_domain.txt', 'route_hosts.txt', 'start.txt', 'space.txt']
for file in fileList:
    try:
        os.remove(file)
    except OSError as e:
        print("File '{}' could not be removed.".format(file))
        # pass # => you really should do more than pass here...
```

This way, it won't short-circuit the program if an error is thrown in one of the earlier files.

Comment: That worked great. thank :)
I will use the print for debug purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem seems to be that you handle exceptions silently so you can't know anything about other problems. You might have more problemas but that one is the most obvious one.

Comment: My point is to handle them silently, if the file excites then delete - if not pass. the user does not need to see error that the file is not there.
When I added errors, the only one that i got is `code WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified:`

Comment: So now you know what your other problem is, one of the specified files does not extst.

Comment: That why it "try", not all files should be there at all times.

Comment: Well as soon as you fail the try is over and the remaining files won'd be deleted.